# android:listview focus on first item

Tags: android, listview, android-emulator, focus

i have custom list with one image as fill parent for relative layout.
on top of image i have text view and another image.
i have set the selector file for list item .
problem is when my application launches it is not showing focus on first item ,which is requirement.
i have tried these things . please guide me more as they are not working .

```
listView.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getBaseContext()));
  listView.setSelection(0);
  listView.setSelected(true);
  listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
  listView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);
  listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
  listView.setSelectionFromTop(0,100);
```

thanks

Comment: You got any other solution puneet? @puneet kaur

Answer (score -1):

Please verify if items in Your list were added before:

```
listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView()
```

Otherwise you will always get last item selected.